# TortoiseGit shows clean directory as conflicted

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have a git repository that I'm working on which I am using TortoiseGit to manage in Windows.  Show modifications and diff show that there are no differences between working directory and head.  However, a little red X shows up over one of my folders.

Is there a way to reset the status of TortoiseGit?  Are there differences I can't see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming it's not a bug in Tortoise Git--I don't use it, so I don't know much about it--it depends what happened most recently. I think the most likely situation is that you ran into a merge conflict during a rebase and forgot to finish the rebase. If that's the case, you need to complete the rebase one way or another: `git rebase --abort` or `git rebase --continue`. A `git status` will give you a clue. If it shows that you're not on a branch, but you expect to be, then you're probably in the middle of a rebase.

**Edit:** This guy [claims it's a problem with the TortoiseGit cache](http://www.benjaminbooth.com/tableorbooth/2011/03/tortoisegit-1630-caching-errors.html) in Windows. Try killing the TGitCache.exe process and restarting explorer. I remember a problem like this in TortoiseSVN back in the day...

Comment: git rebase --abort reports no rebase in progress.  git status says working directory clean :(  I think it might be a bug in TortiseGit?  But I can't imagine what it might be.

Comment: @IslandCow: Updated my answer. Try that out.

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!  I should know better, it's Windows, the solution is always Reboot. :P

Comment: In my experience the icons in TortoiseGit are mostly worthless, being misleading a large proportion of the time. Some seem to stay missing entirely.

Comment: Killing the cache process worked for me. Really annoying to have it give incorrect results though. If I can't trust the icons, it's useless.

Answer (score 7):

Close all Explorer windows (directory windows)

Open Process explorer: Sort by name. Find TGitCache.exe. 
Click on it and press the END PROCESS button.

Reopen the explorer and voilla.